Datatable formatting with JS disappears on button click
I've used some javascript to conditionally format a datatable in Shiny, all works well. However, on clicking of a button the formatting disappears.
I reproducible example is below. The table renders as expected, however, when it is redrawn - if you select how many rows to show or put a value in the search box - the formatting disappears. I'd like it to stay.
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(

 
        mainPanel(
           dataTableOutput("table1")
        )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

    js_format1 <-  c(
        "function(settings) {",
        "  var table = settings.oInstance.api();",
        "  var nrows = table.rows().count();",
        "  for(var i=0; i<nrows; i++){",
        "    var a = table.cell(i,2);",
        "    var b = table.cell(i,3);",
        "      b.node().style.backgroundColor = b.data() >= a.data() ? 'lightgreen' : '#FFCCCB';",
        " }",
        "}")
    
    output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
        dat <- data.frame(A = letters[1:10], a=rep(1,10), b = rep(2,10))
    
            datatable(dat,
                      options = list(initComplete = JS(js_format1)))

        
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


You must use the drawCallback option instead of initComplete.
Here are the modified codes:
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  
  mainPanel(
    dataTableOutput("table1")
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  js_format1 <-  c(
    "function(settings) {",
    "  var table = settings.oInstance.api();",
    "  var nrows = table.rows().count();",
    "  for(var i=0; i<nrows; i++){",
    "    var a = table.cell(i,2);",
    "    var b = table.cell(i,3);",
    "      b.node().style.backgroundColor = b.data() >= a.data() ? 'lightgreen' : '#FFCCCB';",
    " }",
    "}")
  
  output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
    dat <- data.frame(A = letters[1:10], a=rep(1,10), b = rep(2,10))
    
    datatable(dat,
              options = list(drawCallback  = JS(js_format1)))
    
    
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

